# Converting 12VDC to 7..9VDC (20A)

Tags: automotive

I used to have a 3-coil cooling fan that would rotate slow or fast depending on what is powering it - the air conditioner "signal" would make it rotate slower than that of the engine heat sensor.

Now that since a compatible fan is impossible to replace (original one died), I've installed a single-coil 12VDC fan, the only one I could get that would fit perfectly, and combined the AC and engine circuits. The thing works ok, but at full RPM from either A/C or engine temp input.

Now what I want is to separate the two and introduce some kind of a voltage drop on the A/C line - I was thinking of a few high-current diodes, each dropping about 0.7V connected in series, but I'm afraid I will not be able to deal with diodes overheating. Is there a better solution to my problem, or diodes with proper heatsink are ok? We're speaking 15~20Amps here (+ on/off spikes)

here's a diagram explaining the current setup that I would like to modify (decouple the AC and engine temp sensor lines):

```
>- 12vdc from A/C ------------> >-+------3 
                                  |      3 
>- 12vdc from heat sensor ----> >-+      3 * (single-speed fan)
                                         3 
                                 GND ----3
```

and the original (2 separate "inputs"):

```
>- 12vdc from heat sensor ---->  >-------3 
                                         3 
>- 12vdc from A/C ------------>  >-------3 * (2-speed fan, slower from A/C)
                                         3 
                                 GND ----3
```

Answer (score 1):

1/3 HP sounds pretty high for an auxiliary cooling fan. It would be good to get an actual measurement of the current draw (running and starting).

The typical approach used in older cars is to have a series resistor (something like 0.6 ohm for BMW and Mercedes cars). That would imply a current more like 10A from the 12VDC. They're generally in a 25A circuit.

If it's actually drawing 20A running then the current with reduced (say to 9V) voltage will probably be more like 15A so the power in the resistor or diodes would be less than 50W. Since you have a fan to cool them it should not be  problem either way, but the resistor can be allowed to run very hot, whereas you should keep the diodes to well under 100°C case temperature.